# Cortar imagen y enviar al servidor

Tags: android, imagen, upload

Buenas, tengo el siguiente código que permite tomar una foto o seleccionarla desde la galeria y la corta, funciona bastante bien y es adecuado para lo que necesito, ahora bien, una vez que recibo la imagen cortada me gustaria enviarla al servidor, donde sera almacenada, en estos momentos tengo un codigo que funciona un dia si y un dia no, y quiero que funcione siempre, aqui estan los codigos:

Codigo para cortar imagenes (Es el que me gustaria implementar en mi app):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
private ImageView mImageView;
private AlertDialog dialog;

private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    captureImageInitialization();

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SelectImageBtn);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV);


    mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });


}

private void captureImageInitialization() {
    /**
     * a selector dialog to display two image source options, from camera
     * ‘Take from camera’ and from existing files ‘Select from gallery’
     */
    final String[] items = new String[] { "Take from camera",
            "Select from gallery" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
            // camera
            if (item == 0) {
                /**
                 * To take a photo from camera, pass intent action
                 * ‘MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE‘ to open the camera app.
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                /**
                 * Also specify the Uri to save the image on specified path
                 * and file name. Note that this Uri variable also used by
                 * gallery app to hold the selected image path.
                 */
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg"));

                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        mImageCaptureUri);

                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // pick from file
                /**
                 * To select an image from existing files, use
                 * Intent.createChooser to open image chooser. Android will
                 * automatically display a list of supported applications,
                 * such as image gallery or file manager.
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    });

    dialog = builder.create();
}

public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions = options;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon))
                    .setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name))
                    .setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            /**
             * After taking a picture, do the crop
             */
            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            /**
             * After selecting image from files, save the selected path
             */
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

            doCrop();

            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            /**
             * After cropping the image, get the bitmap of the cropped image and
             * display it on imageview.
             */
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
            /**
             * Delete the temporary image
             */
            if (f.exists())
                f.delete();

            break;

    }
}

private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();
    /**
     * Open image crop app by starting an intent
     * ‘com.android.camera.action.CROP‘.
     */
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    /**
     * Check if there is image cropper app installed.
     */
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    /**
     * If there is no image cropper app, display warning message
     */
    if (size == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        /**
         * Specify the image path, crop dimension and scale
         */
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        /**
         * There is posibility when more than one image cropper app exist,
         * so we have to check for it first. If there is only one app, open
         * then app.
         */

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                    res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            /**
             * If there are several app exist, create a custom chooser to
             * let user selects the app.
             */
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent
                        .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                    CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,
                                null);
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }

}



    }
```

Codigo que me funciona y que logro subir imagenes al servidor: 
El problema de este codigo es que a veces no me funciona y se queda pensando, no hace nada y no termina de realizar el proceso, aqui esta el codigo:

```
    //manejo de las imagenes de perfil
private void convertBitmapToString(Bitmap profilePicture) {
    /*
        Base64 encoding requires a byte array, the bitmap image cannot be converted directly into a byte array.
        so first convert the bitmap image into a ByteArrayOutputStream and then convert this stream into a byte array.
    */
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    profilePicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] array = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    profile = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

//luego de buscar la imagen en la galeria, aqui la trae de vuelta al activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //Image Successfully Selected
        try {
            //parsing the Intent data and displaying it in the imageview
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();//Geting uri of the data
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);//creating an imputstrea
            profilePicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);//decoding the input stream to bitmap
            iv_profile.setImageBitmap(profilePicture);
            IMAGE_STATUS = true;//setting the flag
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Luego proceso la imagen y la envio:

```
    convertBitmapToString(profilePicture);
    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(nombre, password, profile, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
```

Hay alguna manera de fusionar los dos codigos?

Comment: "funciona un dia si y un dia no,", no has revisado el LogCat para determinar cual es el error?

Comment: El log no me indica, me imagino que es por el tamaño de la imagen, o que sea png, se que hay veces que la imagen no me funciona, desde el emulador no me muestra el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion:

```
 private void convertBitmapToString(Bitmap iv_profile) {
    /*
        Base64 encoding requires a byte array, the bitmap image cannot be converted directly into a byte array.
        so first convert the bitmap image into a ByteArrayOutputStream and then convert this stream into a byte array.
    */
```

Aqui selecciono la imagen desde la camara y procedo a hacer el crop:

```
private void captureImageInitialization() {
    /**
     * a selector dialog to display two image source options, from camera
     * ‘Take from camera’ and from existing files ‘Select from gallery’
     */
    final String[] items = new String[] { "Tomar desde la cámara",
            "Seleccionar de la galeria" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Seleccione la imagen");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
            // camera
            if (item == 0) {
                /**
                 * To take a photo from camera, pass intent action
                 * ‘MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE‘ to open the camera app.
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                /**
                 * Also specify the Uri to save the image on specified path
                 * and file name. Note that this Uri variable also used by
                 * gallery app to hold the selected image path.
                 */
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg"));

                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        mImageCaptureUri);

                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // pick from file
                /**
                 * To select an image from existing files, use
                 * Intent.createChooser to open image chooser. Android will
                 * automatically display a list of supported applications,
                 * such as image gallery or file manager.
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}

public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
    private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
        super(context, R.layout.crop_selector, options);

        mOptions = options;

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_selector, null);

        CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon))
                    .setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name))
                    .setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class CropOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            /**
             * After taking a picture, do the crop
             */
            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            /**
             * After selecting image from files, save the selected path
             */
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

            doCrop();

            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            /**
             * After cropping the image, get the bitmap of the cropped image and
             * display it on imageview.
             */
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                //Uri imageUri = extras.getParcelable("data");
                profilePicture = photo;
                   iv_profile.setImageBitmap(photo);




            }

            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
            /**
             * Delete the temporary image
             */
            if (f.exists())
                f.delete();

            break;

    }
}

private void doCrop() {
    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();
    /**
     * Open image crop app by starting an intent
     * ‘com.android.camera.action.CROP‘.
     */
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    /**
     * Check if there is image cropper app installed.
     */
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    /**
     * If there is no image cropper app, display warning message
     */
    if (size == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        /**
         * Specify the image path, crop dimension and scale
         */
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        /**
         * There is posibility when more than one image cropper app exist,
         * so we have to check for it first. If there is only one app, open
         * then app.
         */

        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                    res.activityInfo.name));

            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            /**
             * If there are several app exist, create a custom chooser to
             * let user selects the app.
             */
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                        res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent
                        .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                    CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,
                                null);
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }

}

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    iv_profile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] array = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    profile = Base64.encodeToString(array, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

En mi imageView llamo al metodo:

```
  iv_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            captureImageInitialization();

        }
    });
```

Y luego la convierto en Base64 para enviarla a un servidor:

```
     convertBitmapToString(profilePicture);
```